# Hibernate ClassValidator getInvalidValues yielding no errors

Tags: hibernate, spring, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

The following code does not yield any invalid values even though I am filling the model with invalid values.

```
private static ClassValidator<User> userValidator = new ClassValidator<User>(User.class);
InvalidValue[] errors = userValidator.getInvalidValues(user);
List<String> err = new ArrayList<String>();
for (InvalidValue invalidValue : errors) {
    System.out.println(invalidValue.getMessage());
}
```

Adding the User entity class as requested in the comments.

```
@Entity(name = "User")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = MWQueries.nqAllUsers, query = "from User"),
        @NamedQuery(name = MWQueries.nqUserById, query = "from User where id = ?")
})
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5013553611664469461L;

    private Long id;
    private String userName;
    private String email;
    private Role role;
    private @XStreamOmitField String passWord;


    public User() {
    }


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    @Column
    @Length(min = 6, max = 20)
    @NotBlank
    @NotEmpty
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }


    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }


    @Column
    @Length(min = 6)
    @NotBlank
    @NotEmpty
    @JsonIgnore
    public String getPassWord() {
        return passWord;
    }


    public void setPassWord(String passWord) {
        this.passWord = passWord;
    }


    @Column
    public Role getRole() {
        return role;
    }


    public void setRole(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }


    @Column(unique = true)
    @Email
    @NotBlank
    @NotEmpty
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }


    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the line: "List<String> err = new ArrayList<String>();" should be removed, because it does not do anything. -- But really I believe the problem is somewhere else, try to check first that `ClassValidator.hasValidationRules()` returns true.

Comment: It doesn't. It returns false. What can I do to fix that?

Comment: @Y Kamesh Rao: Post the User class please.

Comment: @Ralph I updated the post to include the User class as required by you.

Comment: @Y Kamesh: I can not see anything wrong, have you ever tryed to move all annotations to the fields. (I do not want to to replace it in production, it is just a test)

Comment: Yup....Tried that too...

Comment: I am wondering if something is wrong with the configuration part but never found anything on Google regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only hint I can give you, is to try it a bit different. If this test validation works, than the problem is somewhere in the way you use the validator. If it does not works, then the problem is somewhere in your entity

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import javax.validation.ValidatorFactory;


/** given: an invalid object */
    Demo invalid = new Demo("Hallo Welt");

    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

    /** then there must not be constraint violation */
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Demo>> result = validator.validate(invalid);
```

Comment: Thanks anyways. But it doesn't verify for Duplicate entries. I need to wait until insertion for that contraint violation to be checked.

Comment: Y Kamesh Rao: this does only the JSR303 Validation. I have not seen any dublicate checking contraint. Anyway if you are talking about a hinberate contstraint, then is is done with the database, so this constraint will not been checked until the entity is saved and the transaction committed.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the application level hibernate validator code after validating the javax constraints validates the hibernate validations.

```
public Validity validate(T bean, Class<T> beanClass) {
    List<String> err = new ArrayList<String>();
    ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    javax.validation.Validator validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();

    Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> violations = validator.validate(bean);
    for (ConstraintViolation<T> violation : violations) {
        String propertyPath = violation.getPropertyPath().toString().toLowerCase();
        String message = violation.getMessage();
        String errMsg = WordUtils.capitalize(propertyPath) + " " + message;

        Log.error(EntityValidator.class, "Invalid Value: '" + errMsg);
        err.add(errMsg);
    }

    // Checking for hibernate validations
    err.addAll(hValidate(bean, beanClass));

    return new Validity(err.isEmpty(), err);
}


public List<String> hValidate(T bean, Class<T> beanClass) {
    List<String> err = new ArrayList<String>();
    ClassValidator<T> hValidator = new ClassValidator<T>(beanClass);

    InvalidValue[] hErrs = hValidator.getInvalidValues(bean);

    for (InvalidValue invalidValue : hErrs) {
        err.add(invalidValue.getMessage());
        Log.error(EntityValidator.class, "Invalid Value: '" + invalidValue.getMessage());
    }

    return err;
}
```